# How do I convert hh:mm:ss to hh:mm in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I convert hh:mm:ss to hh:mm in SQL Server?

```
select Count(Page) as VisitingCount,Page,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Date, 108) from scr_SecuristLog   
where Date between '2009-05-04 00:00:00' and '2009-05-06 14:58'  
and [user] in(select USERNAME             
    from scr_CustomerAuthorities )  
group by Page,Date order by [VisitingCount] asc
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, the set of timestamps is not [**well-ordered**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_ordered_set), this means you cannot get a "last" timestamp whose time part up to minutes is `2009-05-06 14:58`.

In `SQL Server`, which keeps the time part of a datetime as a number of `1/300` second fractions after midnight, this "last" timestamp would be `2009-05-06 14:58:59.997`, but this is not guaranteed to be compatible with future releases of with other `TIMESTAMP` storage methods.

That means you'll need to split your `BETWEEN` condition into two conditions, one of which being `strict less` than the next minute:

```
select Count(Page) as VisitingCount,Page,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Date, 108) from scr_SecuristLog   
where Date >= '2009-05-04 00:00:00'
      AND Date < DATEADD(minute, 1, '2009-05-06 14:58')
and [user] in(select USERNAME             
    from scr_CustomerAuthorities )  
group by Page,Date order by [VisitingCount] asc
```

This solution will efficiently use indexes on `Date`

Answer (score 29):

`CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108)`-- Gets only `HH:mm`

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? Using 108 [should](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) get you `hh:mi:ss`. Using what's essentially memory trickery to cut that down seems like the sort of unsupported thing that'll suddenly break in a new version.

Comment: 108 does return `hh:mi:ss` but passing `varchar(5)` as the first param truncates the result to the first 5 characters. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77454910/15740725) for a nice solution in SQL Server 2012+.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(5), GetDate(), 108)
```

Using varchar(5) will automatically truncate the date to remove the seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think there is a built in function; usually do something like this

```
SET @time = '07:45'
SET @date = CONVERT(DATETIME,@time)
SELECT @date

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@date,108),5)
```

Answer (score 2):

For this specific need you should use the between method as noted by [Quassnoi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820155/how-do-i-convert-hhmmss-to-hhmm-in-sql-server/820174#820174). However, the general problem can be solved with:

```
select dateadd(second, -datepart(second, @date), @date)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the RIGHT() function to crop the Date. Something like:

```
RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Date, 108),5)
```

This will only work if number of characters is constant e.g. there is a leading zero if applicable. (Sorry havn't got SQL server here to test).

A better way is to use the T-SQL datepart function to split and then re-concatinate the date parts so:

```
DARTPART("hh", CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Date, 108))+":"+DARTPART("mi", CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Date, 108))
```

**References:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To get hh:mm format from today's date:

```
select getdate()

select convert(varchar(5),getdate(),108)
```

To get hh:mm format from any datetime column in a table data:

```
select date_time_column_name from table_name where column_name = 'any column data name'

select convert(varchar(5),date_time_column_name,108) from table_name
where column_name = 'any column data name'

select creationdate from employee where Name = 'Satya'

select convert(varchar(5),creationdate,108) from employee 
where Name = 'Satya'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS Time(0)) AS VARCHAR(5))
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, it would help others reading your answer if you gave some comments/explanation as what your doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+, use the `format` function.

`SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'HH:mm') as time`

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)